# Is there a possible way to show the traversal path in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, recursion, graph, path, traversal

I was looking in the MongoDB docs and found the $aggregate framework. The operator [$graphLookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsP6q.png) allows the user to perform recursive search. Assume there's a collection like the one below:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron" }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew" }
```

The following table provides a traversal path for the document
 `{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron" }`

[Image for what it provides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUWij.png)

The output generates the hierarchy **Asya -> Ron -> Eliot -> Dev.**

Is there actually a way to show all the paths that -a more complex graph would generate- in MongoDB, or do I have to do it client side(programmatically)? If so, an example would be appreciated.

An example to all paths would be, if there were two more insertions like:

```
{ "_id" : 7, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Bill" }
{ "_id" : 8, "name" : "Bill", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
```

The output in this scenario would generate two paths.

1. **Asya -> Ron -> Eliot -> Dev**
2. **Asya -> Ron -> Eliot -> Bill -> Dev**

Comment: This is a duplicate question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415646/mongodbs-graphlookup-trying-to-get-a-tree-structure Hope that helps