# MongoDB's $graphLookup trying to get a tree structure

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to work with the new MongoDB v3.4 $graphLookup aggregation pipeline. I have this simple tree collection, with some nodes and a parent DBRef:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f2"), "name" : "Root node 1" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5938068abbdbfb36c18a80f5"), "name" : "Child 1.1", "parent" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f2") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593806b0bbdbfb36c18a80f7"), "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1", "parent" : ObjectId("5938068abbdbfb36c18a80f5") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5938068abbdbfb36c18a80f6"), "name" : "Child 1.2", "parent" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f2") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f3"), "name" : "Root node 2" }
```

I would like to get this kind of tree structure:

```
- Root node 1
    - Child 1.1
        - Subchild 1.1.1
    - Child 1.2
- Root node 2
```

So, I'm trying to work with the new $graphLookup aggregation pipeline, like this:

```
db.getCollection('tree').aggregate([
    { $match: { parent: { $exists: false } } },
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "tree",
            startWith: "$_id",
            connectFromField: "_id",
            connectToField: "parent",
            as: "children"
        }
   },
   { $sort: { name: 1 } }
])
```

But my issue is that I get all child of "Root node 1" in one collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f2"),
    "name" : "Root node 1",
    "children" : [
        { "_id" : ObjectId("593806b0bbdbfb36c18a80f7"), "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1", "parent" : ObjectId("5938068abbdbfb36c18a80f5") },
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5938068abbdbfb36c18a80f6"), "name" : "Child 1.2", "parent" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f2") },
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5938068abbdbfb36c18a80f5"), "name" : "Child 1.1", "parent" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f2") }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59380657bbdbfb36c18a80f3"),
    "name" : "Root node 2",
    "children" : [ ]
}
```

I have no idea how to lookup children recursively to get "Subchild 1.1.1" in the children collection of "Child 1.1".
I'm looking for any suggestions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) is not producing the hierarchy of dependencies - it performs a recursive search of connected documents, but results are flattened into the single-dimension array. Here is the quote from the documentation:

> For each matching document, $graphLookup takes the value of the
>   **_id** and checks every document in the **tree** collection for
>   a matching **parent** value. For each match, $graphLookup adds the
>   matching document in the from collection to an array **children**. This step continues recursively until no more
>   matching documents are found, or until the operation reaches a
>   recursion depth specified by the maxDepth parameter.

I.e. it searches for dependent documents recursively, but each found document is added to same children array of the parent document no matter how 'deep' the child is located.

---

Note - you don't see `Child 1.1` with its connected `Subchild 1.1.1` because you are filtering out these documents in `match` stage:

```
{ $match: { parent: { $exists: false } } }
```

that selects only documents which don't have a parent - `"Root node 1"` and `"Root node 2"`. If you will remove this filter, then all other documents with the hierarchy of their dependants will be returned:

```
{
    "name" : "Child 1.1",
    "children" : [ 
        { "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1" }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Child 1.2"
    "children" : []
},
{
    "name" : "Root node 1",
    "children" : [ 
        { "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1" }, 
        { "name" : "Child 1.2" }, 
        { "name" : "Child 1.1" }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Root node 2",
    "children" : []
},
{
    "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1"
    "children" : []
}
```

---

If you don't want to mix children from different 'depth' of tree in single children array, then take a look at interesting comment in documentation

> Setting the maxDepth field to 0 is equivalent to a non-recursive
>   $lookup search stage.

It means that each document will get all its direct children into the children array, and after that lookup will stop without any further recursive search. Output will be

```
{
    "name" : "Child 1.1",
    "children" : [ 
        { "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1" }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Child 1.2"
    "children" : []
},
{
    "name" : "Root node 1",
    "children" : [ 
        { "name" : "Child 1.2" }, 
        { "name" : "Child 1.1" }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Root node 2",
    "children" : []
},
{
    "name" : "Subchild 1.1.1"
    "children" : []
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very complete answer! It's more clear with your explanation: "it performs a recursive search of connected documents, but results are flattened into the single-dimension array".

So basically, $graphLookup can't handle a hierarchy of dependencies. If I need to compute a complete tree structure, it's not the right tool for that. I can recompute the results that you mention in your comment (without the $match) or look for another solution :)

Comment: @JeremyBarthe I have added small update (about maxDepth parameter). And seems thats a little closer to what you want to achieve. At least children from different levels will not be mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for your help! maxDepth can definitely be something interesting in a tree structure. I think the conclusion is that I can't compute the entire tree (I mean in nested levels), but anyway $lookup and $graphLookup are really good features (they were clearly missing in MongoDB).

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy   Does this mean that in mongoDB we can not retrieve a result where we have a tree hierarchy with N-Levels, I have exactly the same problem , I want to retrieve the nodes with children and sub-children etc... in N sublevels. If this is not possible with graphLookup operation do we have any other way! Please help !

Answer (score 1):

Had not found the way to solve it with a `maxDepth` parameter, but the `depthField` one (set simply to `'depth'`, in my case) came to help, and [Jeremy Barthe suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415646/mongodbs-graphlookup-trying-to-get-a-tree-structure#comment75834482_44416045) to recompute results.

Here is a function that recursively rebuilds the `$graphLookup` result.

```
def list_tree_lookup(keys, data, depth=0):
    result = []
    for a in data:
        if a['depth'] + depth == 0 or (a['depth'] == depth and a['_id'] in keys):
            b = copy.deepcopy(a)
            b['children'] = list_tree_lookup(a['children'], data, depth+1)
            del b['depth']
            result.append(b)
    return result
```

I used `import copy` and `copy.deepcopy` just to be sure everything stay in place.

So, when you have

```
rootNode1 = {
    "_id" : "Root node 1",
    "children" : [
        { "_id" : "Subchild 1.1.1", "depth" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "Child 1.2", "depth" : 0 },
        { "_id" : "Child 1.1", "depth" : 0 }
    ]
}
```

calling `list_tree_lookup([], rootNode1['children'])` will produce

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Child 1.1"
        "children": [
            { "_id": "Subchild 1.1.1" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "Child 1.2"
        "children": []
    }
]
```

and it can be assigned back to `rootNode1['children']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const allItems = await db.getCollection('tree').find({});
    if (allItems.length) {
        allItems = allItems.map((item) =>
            item.toObject()
        );
        allItems = allItems
            .map((item) => {
                let parentObj = null;
                if (item.parent_id) {
                    parentObj = allItems.find(
                        (findItem) =>
                            findItem._id.toString() ===
                            item.parent_id.toString()
                    );
                }
                if (parentObj) {
                    if (!parentObj.children) {
                        parentObj.children = [];
                    }
                    parentObj.children.push(item);
                }
                return item;
            })
            .filter((item) => !item.parent_id);
    } else {
        console.error("items not found");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please expand on this? And add any references if you have some.